# Backbone not working in Rails

Tags: backbone.js

I've added the gem `'backbone-on-rails'` to my project, did the `rails g backbone:install` command

I added this to my backbone > views > index file (which gets rendered) but I don't see the "Hello world" in my #container on my homepage.

```
class Movieseat.Views.MovieseatsIndex extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['movieseats/index']

  # el - stands for element. Every view has a element associate in with HTML content will be rendered.
  el: "#container"

  # It's the first function called when this view it's instantiated.
  initialize: ->
    @render()

  # $el - it's a cached jQuery object (el), in which you can use jQuery functions to push content. Like the Hello World in this case.
  render: ->
    @$el.html "Hello World"
```

I thought this would render the html "Hello world" into the #container div.

Comment: Does anything create a new instance of that view? Is there a `#container` element on the page when the view is instantiated?

Comment: What do you mean with "instantiated"? Should I make some reference on my homepage where I want the "Hello world" message, I do have a #container div on my homepage? Also nothing is creating a instance of that view.

Comment: By "instantiated" I mean "create an instance of the view", i.e. `new Movieseat.Views.MovieseatsIndex`. Something has to create an instance of the view or nothing will happen.

Comment: Is there something I have to add on my homepage (the view from Rails) to "call" the instance from backbone? I've added `movieseat = new MovieseatsIndex({})` to my index located in the view folder.

Comment: You need a `new Movieseat.Views.MovieseatsIndex` somewhere in your (Java|Coffee)Script. Maybe in your view, maybe inside a `$ ->` wrapper right in that CoffeeScript file, where ever makes sense for how you have things set up.

Comment: By adding `:javascript
  $(function() {
    // MovieSeat is the app name
    new Movieseat.Views.MovieseatsIndex
  });` to my index view of my Rails app I've got the template to load :) cheers.